# OpenJDK detected after uninstall

Tags: java, openjdk, oracle

I'm trying to install and run the STM32CubeProgrammer app (a `.linux` file) on Ubuntu. When I first ran it, I got this professional-looking error:

[image]

I spent hours trying a lot of stuff, including installing OpenJFX, OpenJDK-8 etc. Nothing worked. Now, I've just done my best to purge OpenJDK entirely and installed Oracle Java 11.02 (which should contain this Java FX, I assume?). `java -version` gives:

```
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

JAVA_HOME has been set and JAVA_HOME/bin added to PATH. There are no other java-alternatives present, as far as I know. I've also redirected the `default-java` symlink to point to the new Oracle path. And yet, I still get this error. I've already tried deleting the STM32Programmer installation folder and re-installing just in case; its official `uninstaller.jar` also doesn't work apparently.

- So, assuming the app is still sane and there's really still some lingering OpenJDK artifacts causing this error, where would they be? Is there any place else I should check to completely remove OpenJDK?
- The error says to download Oracle JRE but there's no explicit JRE folder in my installation, even if `java` and `javac` still work. Does this matter?
- The STM32 `.linux` app seemed to install in a single folder in my home directory. Since the uninstaller doesn't work (it just spits out some log data), I deleted the installation folder instead. Are there other folders to check in cases like this, to ensure everything got purged?

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: What does this output? `apt list --installed | grep -e jdk -e jre`

Comment: @AndroidDev I get this: `default-jdk-headless/disco,now 2:1.11-71 amd64 [installed,automatic]
default-jdk/disco,now 2:1.11-71 amd64 [installed]
default-jre-headless/disco,now 2:1.11-71 amd64 [installed,automatic]
default-jre/disco,now 2:1.11-71 amd64 [installed]`

Comment: Ahhh... yeah so you have `default-jdk` installed, which is `openjdk`. Go ahead and do `sudo apt purge default-jdk default-jre`

Comment: @AndroidDev I haven't tried that yet but it turns out the STM32 app is at fault checking for a non-existent folder (something like `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/javafx.properties`) and then throwing the same error if it can't find it. I found this in a script inside its package. Both Oracle and OpenJDK no longer ship the `jre` folder or `JavaFX` by default, so the check always fails. So the problem isn't OpenJDK remnants, just a stupid deceptive error message thrown by the app. I eventually gave up on it and just went with the open-source `stm32flash` CLI app.

Answer (score 0):

Gents, I'd spent hours researching the selfsame issue with the STM32CubeProgrammer, so thanks for taking this most of the way. I came to this late and having assumed that my installation of Ubuntu would, by default, provide all the required ingredients. In any case, I've gone ahead and purged the java that I had installed under my faulty assumptions.

Step 1 java -version produced the following:

openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

Step 2 sudo apt-get purge openjdk* produced:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk*'
... and so on

Step 3 sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer produced:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
... Ok, just another setback most of you would have anticipated!

Step 4 sudo apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libopenjfx-java is already the newest version (8u161-b12-1ubuntu2).
libopenjfx-java set to manually installed.
libopenjfx-jni is already the newest version (8u161-b12-1ubuntu2).
libopenjfx-jni set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  efibootmgr libfwup1 libwayland-egl1-mesa openjfx-source
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  icedtea-8-plugin fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-wqy-microhei fonts-wqy-zenhei
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  openjfx
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 101 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04 [27.5 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20180516ubuntu1~18.04.1 [12.2 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04 [69.7 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 openjfx amd64 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 [33.6 kB]
Fetched 27.6 MB in 5min 59s (76.7 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.
(Reading database ... 164080 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04) …
...

Step 5 Hold the package: as per post by Ehsan in a related thread

sudo apt-mark hold openjfx libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni

Step 6 ls -l of the STM32 install directory
/usr/local/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin
total 17220
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    4096 Apr  2 04:47 ExternalLoader
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Apr  2 04:47 FlashLoader
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Apr  2 04:47 HSM
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2715616 Feb 20 17:35 libcrypto.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  548696 Feb 20 17:35 libssl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  382309 Sep 11  2019 libstp11_SAM.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     354 Apr  2 04:47 libstp11_SAM.so.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Apr  2 04:47 PersoPackages
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Apr  2 04:47 platforms
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Apr  2 04:47 RSSe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     163 Dec  9 23:30 STM32CubeProgrammer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7727803 Feb 20 17:44 STM32CubeProgrammerLauncher
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1645912 Feb 20 17:35 STM32MP_KeyGen_CLI
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1673192 Feb 20 17:35 STM32MP_SigningTool_CLI
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1808746 Feb 20 17:42 STM32_Programmer_CLI
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     147 Apr 18  2018 STM32_Programmer.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  803594 Feb 20 17:42 STM32TrustedPackageCreator
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  277313 Feb 20 17:42 STM32TrustedPackageCreator_CLI

Step 7 launch of the Cube Programmer shell

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    STM32CubeProgrammer v2.4.0                  
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Usage : 
STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe [command_1] [Arguments_1][[command_2] [Arguments_2]...]

Generic commands:

-?, -h, --help         : Show this help

Step 8 launch of the Cube Programmer from the terminal produced a lot of messages as follows:

/usr/local/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin$ ./STM32CubeProgrammer
Gtk-Message: 12:37:27.325: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
No properties file found
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/carlos/.STM32CubeProgrammer/config.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
... but it did launch, also [screen shot of Cube Programmer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrwTN.png) as tested from the desktop and connected to the "blue pill" via serial

Hope this helps! Rgds, C